# Change class using td :nth base from number

Tags: jquery

I tried to access a table data in jQuery to change it's class using the `:nth` selector but it don't work. Maybe I miss something. See sample code below:

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#hit" ).click(function() {
    bar = +($('#num').text()) + 1;
    $("tr td:nth-child(bar)").toggleClass('on');
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}

.off {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="num">1</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="on">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<button id="hit">Hit me!</button>
```

Comment: You're not properly concatenating your bar variable in `$("tr td:nth-child(bar)")`. Also, assuming you fixed that, your logic seems flawed as all your code would do is add and remove the on class from `<td class="off">`. So it would be either that or `<td class="off on">`

Comment: Thanks for that @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#hit" ).click(function() {
    bar = +($('#num').text()) + 1;
    $("tr td:nth-child("+bar+")").toggleClass('on off');
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}

.off {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="num">1</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="on">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<button id="hit">Hit me!</button>
```

I think you want to toggle `on` and `off` you need to have both class in toggle.
Also concat properly

Comment: happy coding mate :) glad to help

Answer (score 1):

use of the variable `bar` is not proper, as per your current code its being used as string `bar`, you need to change

```
...
$("tr td:nth-child(bar)").toggleClass('on');
...
```

to

```
...
$("tr td:nth-child(" + bar + ")").toggleClass('on');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a little bit off.  For starters, you aren't referencing bar as a variable but instead just including the string "bar" in the selector string.  Secondly, toggleClass() is fine, but you'll need to toggle both .on and .off, otherwise your browser will attempt to apply both styles (as ".off" will still be a class of the nth-child).  See below for code:

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#hit" ).click(function() {
    bar = +($('#num').text()) + 1;
    $("tr td:nth-child(" + bar + ")").toggleClass('on off');
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}

.off {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="num">1</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="on">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="off">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<button id="hit">Hit me!</button>
```

Just as an aside, here are some other things you might want to do:
 - Update the value of $('#num') after the click event has fired
 - Check to ensure there exists an nth-child